# Naturally occuring counting process with a 1/log asymptotics?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics, stochastic-processes, prime-numbers

Besides prime numbers, is there another physically realizable counting process that exhibits a 1/log density ? The reason I am posting this question is that we are measuring the response of a quantum tunneling based counting device and it is showing 1/log asymptotics which we have matched up to 50 million primes. The measurement results can be found here

https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11032

In other words, is the 1/log density unique to prime number generation ? 
Any suggestions would be helpful before we set up an experiment to precisely measure the electron transport process.

Comment: I thought the density of primes was not $1/\log x$ but $1/\log x - 1/\log^2 x$ --- is the difference significant on the range of your experiment?

Comment: Primes are $1/\log x$ at least in the sense that $\pi(x)/x$ is asymptotic to $1/\log x$.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "counting process" is here. Do you mean, for example, a sequence $a_n$ solving some counting problem such that $a_n \sim \frac{n}{\log n}$, or do you mean more specifically a subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $|S \cap [n]| \sim \frac{n}{\log n}$?

Comment: I also have no idea what "physically realizable" should mean here.

Comment: Since in our experiment we are counting electrons, the underlying process measures \sum_n \in \mathcal{N} I(n) where I(.) is an indicator function and n refers to time-instants when the electrons tunnel through.

Answer (score 13):

No. One can create many sets of integers whose density decays like 1/log. An easy variant of the set of primes is the set of integers $n$ not divisible by any prime less than $n^\alpha$, for some fixed $0<\alpha<\frac12$.

Here's another example: the set of all integers $n$ such that $n$ is divisible by the number of digits of $n$. (So all one digit numbers, all even two-digit numbers, all three-digit multiples of 3, ..., all ten-digit numbers ending in 0, etc.) The number of digits of $n$ is $\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \rfloor + 1$, so the 1/log behavior emerges naturally from the definition.

A stranger possibility is to take numbers $n$ such that both $n$ and $n+1$ can be written as the sum of two squares, $n=a^2+b^2$ and $n+1=c^2+d^2$. The set of numbers that can be written as the sum of two squares has density decaying like 1/sqrt(log), and this "twin" construction essentially multiplies those two "probabilities" together (up to the leading constant).

As a general rule: when people see that the set of primes has a particular property, they tend to overestimate how unique the set of primes is with respect to that property (or how characteristic that property is of the set of primes).

Comment: Thanks for the examples. Would you know if there are physical systems that can implement these different discrete process ? For our device, we are counting the number of electrons so the underlying stochastic process is measuring the total counts \sum_{n \in N} I(n) where I(.) is an indicator function and n is time instant representing the occurrence of an event.

Comment: A program running on a computer is a physical system....

Comment: Another simple counting process having the same density would be any (typical) realization of Cramer's random model of the primes. In this model, for each positive integer x you decide independently with probability 1/log x if it is prime or not. Obviously this gives a sequence with density 1/log. Also, I suppose this is "physically realizable" (by throwing some sort of dice), whatever this term might mean.

Comment: The question is where does the 1/log x probability arise from. At the fundamental level a physical system is a realization of a quantum mechanical system defined by a system evolution. There is this notion of reimannian that defines this evolution but that system is only hypothetical and to our knowledge we dont know of a device that implements it.